# Creating a html page inside of it ruby code

Tags: ruby

I want to create .html static page, inside of it i put ruby code like

puts "Hello Ruby!"

Ruby is installed, I just don't want to to use any framework for now as I need to understand the language in under the hood first.

What beside the .html page i need to upload it to my server and test it out?

In php i simple type:

```
<h1><?php echo "Hello PHP!"; ?></h1>
```

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to generate the whole thing in ruby but I think you could do something like

```
require 'erb'
my_page = <<EOS
<html>
  <body>
    <p><%= 'Hello ERB!' %></p>
  </body>
</html>
EOS
ERB.new(my_page).result(binding)
```

Comment: You'd need to `require 'erb'` too. Check out the docs for more info: [erb.rb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)